# My Map Annotations in iOS 6 do not stay rotated when the user pans the map

Tags: iphone, ios6, annotations, rotatetransform

In the answer to a similar question the user said to do the following:

The fix for this is to do the following in the viewForAnnotation method:

```
// iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
if (is6orMore) {
     [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)]; //any small positive rotation
}
```

I have tried putting this code all over the place and my annotations still rotate when the map is panned.  Here is my code.

I call this method anytime the map is rotated

```
-(void)rotateAnnotations {

    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
    {
        MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];

        [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- self.mapRotationRadians)];
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[FlagAnnotation class]]) {
            [annotationView setSelected:YES animated:NO];
        }
         [annotationView setNeedsDisplay];  //ios6
    }
}
```

The original answer said to put the bug work around code in the viewForAnnotation method.  Here is that code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

   if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[FlagAnnotation class]]) {

        // once flag is set allow for doubleTap zoom
        [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

        static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

        if (!annotationView)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FlagRed"];
            annotationView.draggable = YES;
            [self updateFlagCoordinate:(MKPlacemark *)annotationView.annotation];
            return annotationView;

        }
        else {
            [self updateFlagCoordinate:(MKPlacemark *)annotationView.annotation];
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        // iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
        if (osVersion() >= 6) {
            [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)];
        }

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

After playing with the code some more I found that I did have the bug fix in the wrong location within viewForAnnotation.  I had the code here:

```
if (!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FlagRed"];
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        [self updateFlagCoordinate:(MKPlacemark *)annotationView.annotation];
        return annotationView;

    }
    else {
        [self updateFlagCoordinate:(MKPlacemark *)annotationView.annotation];
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    // iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
    if (osVersion() >= 6) {
        [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)];
    }

    return annotationView;
```

And I needed to put it here:

```
if (!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FlagRed"];
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        [self updateFlagCoordinate:(MKPlacemark *)annotationView.annotation];

        // iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
        if (osVersion() >= 6) {
            [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)];
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
```

Hopefully that helps someone who has the same issue.

Comment: How do you rotate the map? I changed from old style animation to blocks, but now i have an inexplainable  endless loop in rotation once i start to pan.